# One row is added automatically when I send file to other computer

Tags: excel

I have created one excel file in windows using Mac bootcamp and when I share this file to my other computer running windows, it automatically adds one row to end of every page, Is there any solution to prevent this, I only want 44 rows in my all pages (within same sheet).

[Row difference in Mac bootcamp (Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo2fs.jpg)

[Row difference in my other computer (Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYqJB.png)

Comment: Isn't it a printing config? For example, one computer ir set to A4 sheets and the other to letter sheets.

Comment: @FernandoBarbosa I have custom margins but they are same on both computers and print setting is on A4 sheets